# Difference between a munkar hadith and a mudtarib hadith?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

i search it form site and read different scenario but am confused whats the actually difference.
explain me the actual difference of munkar and mudtarib hadith.

Answer (score 1):

The Scholars of Hadith differed over the meanings of the classifications of Hadith. However, what is generally meant by Munkar is that 1. the Isnad is weak, for example there may be a break in the Isnad or one of its narrators lost his memory and 2. the meaning of the Matn opposes something more authentic than it which is established.

Mudtarib refers to the narration which is 'mixed up' either in its Isnad or in its Matn or both. An example of this is when a narrator reports the individuals or the names of individuals in the wrong order or when he mixes the wordings of two different Hadith together.

Both Munkar and Mudtarib are types of weak Hadith but Mudtarib is more specific. Note that a Munkar Hadith can be graded as such because it is Mudtarib in both its Isnad and its Matn.